# Gradle task assemble+ FlavorName +Release not found

Tags: android, dependencies, gradle, task

I'm having problems with Gradle trying to define dependencies and order as well. 
My idea is execute a task which depends on assembleDevRelease & clean. Being clean executed first of all and Dev my flavor.

```
task myTask(dependsOn: ["assembleDevRelease", "clean"])<<{ ... }
```

I've tried different ways to call "assembleDevRelease" and add the "mustRunAfter clean".
that only works when I only use "assemble" not when I add the flavor name and the "Release" option.

This [link](http://mrhaki.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/gradle-goodness-working-with-live-task.html) explains really well how to add dependencies however I don't managed to get the task assembleDevRelease.

Could someone explain me why I cannot find this task?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For them which have had this issue too, I've just managed to solve it adding this code:

```
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name.contains('assemble') ) {
        task.mustRunAfter clean
    }
}
```

It might be a bit dirty but it works.

Answer (score 0):

**mine solution** eg. when i wanna use build type incremented on release for  flavors:

```
    // obtain tasks names
    List<String> runTasks = gradle.startParameter.getTaskNames();

    for (String item : runTasks)
        // increment only version on task which contains word assemble & Release
        if (item.contains('assemble') && item.contains('Release')) {
            value = 1;    // <- u can use here  "item.mustRunAfter clean"
        }
```